# 'cat' not displaying line breaks

Tags: macos, command-line

For some reason `cat` no longer shows line breaks when I use it, while all other tools (`grep`, `more` etc) do.

I am using iterm2 on OSX 10.11.4.

What could be causing this behaviour?

**Example**

I have a file `test.txt`created in vim:

```
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
```

When I do `cat test.txt` the output is (note space in place of newline):

```
this is a test this is a test this is a test
```

Answer (score 2):

These things can occur based on a whole bunch of small issues, either in the shell used, the terminal application used, the file format or something else altogether.

To triage, the following steps may be useful

- run `cat -vet test.txt` to see whether there are additional characters in the file
- run `(echo a; echo b)|cat` to see if it depending on the input data
- switch terminal applications to see if this is the cause
- run `bash --noprofile` to see whether something is lurking in the shell configuration

In my case someone had modified 'cat' behaviour in .bashrc

Comment: There is some cause other than these. I have the same problem and they don't tell me anything.